# jQuery validate not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validate() and when I simply have:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    onfocusout: function (valueToBeTested) {
        if($(valueToBeTested).hasClass('required')){
            if(this.element(valueToBeTested)){
                $(valueToBeTested).addClass('valid');
            } else{
                $(valueToBeTested).addClass('invalid');
            };
        };
    }
    rules:
        {
      ...(rules here)
    }
});
```

it works fine. But when I try to add something like `onkeyup` or `submitHandler`:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    onfocusout: function (valueToBeTested) {
        if($(valueToBeTested).hasClass('required')){
            if(this.element(valueToBeTested)){
                $(valueToBeTested).addClass('valid');
            } else{
                $(valueToBeTested).addClass('invalid');
            };
        };
    },
    submitHandler: function(i){
        var badForm = false;
        var errmsg = "<img src=\"invalid.png\"/><br/>";
        var $required_fields = $(".required");
        $required_fields.each( function(i) { 
            if(!($(i).valid())){
                errmsg += $(i).name + " is required<br/>";  
                badForm = true;
            }

            if(badForm){
                alert("bad");
                $('#errdiv').html(errmsg).show();
                window.scrollTo(0,0);   
            }
        });
    },
    rules:
        {
       ...
    }
});
```

it starts not working:
1) in this scenario, it seems to never even enter the `submitHandler` block. Same when I try to duplicate the `onfocusout` functionality inside an `onkeyup` block.
2) when the second block is present, it messes with the `onfocusout` block in the sense that the `onfocusout` block will work the first time on any given field, then not again.

I feel that I'm missing something obvious since I think I'm doing what the documentation says. I want the validation to happen on all three. The `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` are pretty much the same, but the `submitHandler`should do the same, plus populate and show the error div.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Completely remove your custom `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` functions**.   You are totally misusing these.

The `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` functions only control ***how*** validation is triggered and you have broken this functionality.

Adding/removing the error/valid classes is already being done automatically by default on keyup and focusout.  If you need to over-ride how classes are applied, you would write custom `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions.  However, based on your code, I see no reason to do this either.  You would only need to change the error class from the default `error` into `invalid`.

```
errorClass: "invalid",
validClass: "valid" // <- default value
```

---

As far as the `submitHandler`, as per docs it only fires when the form is valid, so it's useless to put a conditional inside that tests for validity.

You also would never put code in the `submitHandler` that has anything to do with the error messages or their HTML structure.  You would use `errorPlacement` and/or `errorElement` for this.  The `success` option is used for leveraging the message label elements when the field is valid, since they're normally hidden in this case.  You would use `showErrors`, `errorContainer`, and `errorLabelContainer` to construct a centralized error message box.

**I suggest you [refer to the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) to learn how the various options and functions are properly used.**

In other words, you seem to be trying to force the plugin to do what it's already supposed to be doing.  By improperly over riding these designated options, you're breaking the plugin, and it's still somewhat unclear what you're ultimately trying to achieve.  If you're only trying to over-ride the default assigned classes, you don't need to re-write all the default functionality, just use the `errorClass` and `validClass` options.

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    errorClass: "invalid",
    validClass: "valid", // <- already the default value, not needed to specify
    rules: {
        ...
    }
});
```

**Simple demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/9ax47efu/**

---

**EDIT**:

After many comments, it was determined that the OP wants to switch the validation behavior from "Lazy" to "Eager".

Defaults modified to remove "Lazy" validation...

```
onkeyup: function(element, event) {
    var excludedKeys = [
        16, 17, 18, 20, 35, 36, 37,
        38, 39, 40, 45, 144, 225
    ];
    if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "" || $.inArray(event.keyCode, excludedKeys) !== -1) {
        return;
    } else {
        this.element(element);
    }
},
onfocusout: function(element) {
    if (!this.checkable(element)) {
        this.element(element);
    }
}
```

**DEMO 2: http://jsfiddle.net/c8zq6bzu/**

Comment: Thanks. I've actually moved past this code. While I was waiting for someone to answer, I figured it out. :)

Comment: Ok, so you're saying if I simply put errorClass: "invalid" it'll handle that part, but what about the valid class? Where would I define that one?

Comment: Ok, I tried that and it didn't work. I'm getting errors:
 $("#myForm").validate({
  onfocusout: true,
  onkeyup: true, 
  errorClass: "invalid",
  rules:
   {...}
 });

Comment: @ReverendDovie, as stated in my answer, **refer to the documentation**.  [`true` is not a valid parameter for the `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onfocusout) and likely causing new problems.

Comment: @ReverendDovie, *"but what about the valid class?"* ~ **again**, [refer to the documentation for this](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#validclass).

Comment: I actually took out those two lines, and it still ignores the errorClass.

Comment: I run that fiddle on chrome and nothing changes.

Comment: @ReverendDovie, click "submit" and the error class is applied as evidenced by the red border.  Satisfy the rule and the valid class is applied as evidenced by the green border... pretty simple stuff.   Do you have JavaScript turned on in your browser?

Comment: Oh, I was looking for the onfocusout and onkeyup parts to be working as well. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @ReverendDovie, they do work as well.   After clicking "submit", fill out the field and then delete the characters from the field.  [As per documentation, validation is "Lazy" by default](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo)... nothing happens until the initial click of the submit button.

Comment: That's the thing. I want it to check even before the submit button is clicked.

Comment: @ReverendDovie, see my updated answer for showing you how to switch from "Lazy" to "Eager" validation.